# Bootstrap 4 : "Don't show me again" on a modal checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a modal with a checkbox saying "Don't show me again". 
When I click that checkbox and then press the button "Close" I want my modal to disappear 'forever'.

I'm using jquery-cookie but I can't figure out why it is not working.

When I check the checkbox and the press the 'close' button and reload the page, the modal will comeback ..

Here's my code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WBPLEK

Here's just the JS part :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    if ($.cookie('cacher-modal')) {
        $("#popupMaintenanceModal").remove();
    }
    else {
        $('#popupMaintenanceModal').modal('show');
    }

    if ($('#popupMaintenanceCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(".btn-maintenance").click(function () {
            $("#popupMaintenanceModal").remove();
            $.cookie('cacher-modal', true);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: are you storing this "Don't show me again" value?

Comment: No. You have all my code there

Comment: ` $.cookie('cacher-modal', 'true');`

Comment: Nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting your cookie when the window checkbox is clicked. Instead, you need to add a click event listener to your checkbox and then check if it is checked/unchecked and set the appropriate cookies. Also, to hide the modal, you can use:

```
$("#popupMaintenanceModal").modal("hide");
```

To properly close the modal.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if ($.cookie("cacher-modal")) {
    $("#popupMaintenanceModal").remove();
  } else {
    $("#popupMaintenanceModal").modal("show");
  }

  $("#popupMaintenanceCheckbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#popupMaintenanceModal").modal("hide");
        $.cookie("cacher-modal", true);
    } else {
      $.cookie("cacher-modal", false);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I was misunderstanding the cookies. It's clear know :) Thank's

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks :)